# Describing a p-adic number through its truncations, obtaining a p-adic number from a p-adically coherent sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic, infinity, p-adic-number-theory

I am currently working through *p-adic numbers, an introduction* by Fernando Q. Gouvêa.

I understand the result that, if $a$ is a non-zero quadratic residue mod $p$, i.e. there is some $q$ such that $q^2 \equiv a \mod p$, then there is $q_k$ such that $q_k^2 \equiv a \mod p^k$ and $q_{k+1} \equiv q_k \mod p^k$ for every integer $k$. In other words, from $q$ we may construct a $p$-adically coherent sequence $(q)_k$ such that $q_k^2 \equiv a \mod p^k$.

It is intuitive to me that we can construct a $p$-adic number that solves $X^2 = a$, however I'm unsure about the formalisation.

The solution to question 22, which works through such an example, suggests to use truncation. Is this suggesting that if $(q_k)^2 \equiv a \mod p^k$ for all $k$, where $(q_k)$ is the $p$-adic number $q$ truncated to $k$ terms, then $q^2 = a$ ? How may I understand this ?

I understand the text is relatively informal, hence I would appreciate help (or resources) to understand how we deal with infinity in this case.

Comment: Did you see the notation $\Bbb{Z}_p=\varprojlim_{k\to \infty} \Bbb{Z}/p^k\Bbb{Z}$ already? (projective limit) It says that the $p$-adic integers is the set/group/ring of sequences $(c_k)$ with $c_k\in \Bbb{Z}/p^k\Bbb{Z}$ and $c_{k+1}\equiv c_k \bmod p^k$. That's the definition of $p$-adics, your sequence $(q_k)$ is an element of that ring and its square is equal to $a$ (represented by the sequence $(a_k)$ with $\forall k, a_k\equiv a\bmod p^k$)